# Error EADDRINUSE when requiring socket.io server through multiple files

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to export socket.io server through multiple node script so i can emit notification on the same port.

Here is my main **server.js** file code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = module.exports.app = express();

const options = {};

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
exports.io = io;

server.listen(3000, function()  {
    console.log('Node.js Global app is running...');
});
```

Below is other node script are runninig when i try to require server.js i get this error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000

**server_tn.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports.app = express();

var code_pays = path.basename(__dirname);
console.log('Node.js app is running...' + code_pays);

var main = require('./../main.js');
var importIo = require('./../server');
var io = importIo.io;

main.mainTraitement(code_pays);
```

Comment: You are exporting a net server, not an instance of net server. You probably wants to share an instance.. By the way, you should use request to reach your net instance, this is the most re-usable way I think.

Comment: Is it possible to export an instance of net server ?

Comment: What about search before opening useless thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28051798/8126612

Comment: the issue is when i require socket.io using `var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
` i get the error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one program listenning to a specific port.
Check if you have any program listening on port 3000, or if on your main.js you are also listenning on port 3000.

Comment: I'm running one node server (server.js) listening on port 3000, but what i'm trying to is to using this instance in multiple files (server_tn.js) so i cant emit notification to node client using socket.io